# What happened to Jenny Jones?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, luther

In *Luther* season 2 Jenny is living with Luther in his apartment.

> Where she accidently kills Kent.

Luther and Jenny both are able to handle that situation and in the end of season 2 it looks like Jenny will continue to live in Luther's apartment for some time.

But in season 3 we have no sign of Jenny. What happened to her?

*1. Has she started a new job and lives on her own?*

*2. Did she go back to live with her mom?*

*3. Or am I asking this question too early and have to watch season 4 first?*